# Hibernate criteria results in redundant left outer join in the generated SQL

Tags: hibernate

I have one problem in one-to-many mapping using hibernate.

I have 2 classes, `Person` and `Address`. `Person` is mapped by `Address` ( one-to-many). I want get all Person `where Address = "xxxx" and person_name like '%8888%'`. I have defined hibernate mapping file with Person and address classes with the many-to-one relationship

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class,"per")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("fname", obj.getInt("fname")))             
    .createCriteria("Addresses","add")                  .add(Restrictions.ilike("address",fieldValue,MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

In the generated query redundant left join is added along with default inner join. How to disable/remove the left outer joins from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class,"per")
    .createAlias("per.addresses","add")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("per.fname", obj.getInt("fname")))
    .add(Restrictions.ilike("add.address",fieldValue,MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```